# Where can I get the source code for the WTP(Web tools platform)

Tags: eclipse-wtp

I'd like to extend the WTP(e.g. custom personal wizard), I need to view the source code for WTP, then I can extend it.

BTW, I want to create my own "WTP", not just creating a personal wizard. Do you know where is the source code? So I can attach it to Eclipse and investigate it

Where can I get the source code for WTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to see the source of WTP to create a personal wizard. There is enough documentation (like [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-BuildingProjectFacets/tutorial.html), an Eclipse article!). To be more specific for your problem, [here is the link](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-BuildingProjectFacets/tutorial.html#adding.wizard.pages) to create your own personal wizards!

Comment: Thanks Styxxy, but I do need the source of WTP, I want to create my own "WTP", not just creating a personal wizard. Do you know where is the source code? So I can attach it to Eclipse and investigate it.

Comment: I am going to wish you very much luck on your project. If you even can't find the source code yourself, I doubt your project has any chance of succeeding. Anyway, this is the project page ( http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=webtools ) where you also can find a link to the source code (seems to be down at this very moment though). And else, there are always search engines to provide you with many links.